# Getting a json object which has a specific key value pair using python 3

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a json object as follows

```
"people":{ 
  {"id":1, "name":"john"}, 
  {"id":2, "name":"sam"} 
}
```

How can I filter out the json object where "id":1 using python 3?. Is there a way to do this without looping? The desired condition would be

If person in people exits where id =1:

then print(person)

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple with python, use the builtin `json` library to [parse your json string](j = json.loads('{"one" : "1", "two" : "2", "three" : "3"}')

```
data = json.loads("'people':{{'id':1, 'name':'john'}, {'id':2, 'name':'sam'} }")
```

Then you can filter your data with [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
filtered_data = {d for d in data['people'] if d['id']==1]
```

To print the result, you could use `next` (second arg is the default value, if no result is returned):

```
print(next(filtered_data, "No result"))
```